# WPF TabControl with Materials Design (without Dragablz)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs, material-design

So, I installed this "Material Design In XAML" package and it smoothly changed all my controls to be more stylish.

Only the tab control seems to have an old design. I looked it up, but only thing I can find is this "Dragablz Tab Control" that you can drag and tear. Well, I don't want my users to drag or tear my tabs.

So, I'm looking for a way to either skin my tabcontrol like the other controls. Or to make Dragablz tabcontrol un-draggable and un-tearable. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here an example of a Dragablz tabcontrol un-draggable and un-tearable:

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl FixedHeaderCount="3">
   <TabItem Header="HELLO">
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Hello World</TextBlock>
   </TabItem>
   <TabItem Header="MATERIAL">
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Material Design</TextBlock>
   </TabItem>
   <TabItem Header="DESIGN">
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Looks Quite Nice</TextBlock>
   </TabItem>                             
</dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

You can set the **FixedHeaderCount** attribute value as the number of tabs on your tabscontrol to make these tabs fixed. (As you can see from the [source](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz/blob/master/Dragablz/TabablzControl.cs))

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows a the first adjacent tabs to be fixed (no dragging, and default close button will not show).
/// </summary>
public int FixedHeaderCount
{
   get { return (int) GetValue(FixedHeaderCountProperty); }
   set { SetValue(FixedHeaderCountProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Although a solution be aware that using Dragablz introduces some specific conditions. One that comes to my mind is inability to disable or hide its tabs (Tab Items).

Comment: Not very compatible with .NetCore

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [MaterialDesignExtensions](https://github.com/spiegelp/MaterialDesignExtensions). They have a style for TabControl, among other things.

1. First install the Nuget package and add the styles to your App.xaml [like in this example](https://github.com/spiegelp/MaterialDesignExtensions/blob/master/MaterialDesignExtensionsDemo/App.xaml)

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <!-- Other MaterialDesign resource stuff -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/MaterialDesignLightTheme.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

2. Then, just style your tab control:

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabControl}">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <!-- Your tab content -->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <!-- Your tab content --> 
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

It looks pretty good:

[image]

Comment: This looks great! Any idea how to switch between light and dark themes using this? Using the standard switch for MDIX's PaletteHelper doesn't affect these extensions.

Comment: Short answer @colin-zabransky
`private static void SetMaterialExtensionTheme(bool isDark)
        {
            var paletteHelper = new MaterialDesignExtensions.Themes.PaletteHelper();
            paletteHelper.SetLightDark(isDark);
        }`